# How does a BIOS determine the amount of available RAM?

Tags: boot, memory, bios, 16-bit

If the BIOS is a 16-bit program running in real mode, and in this mode it possible to address only 1MB, how does the BIOS determine the amount of available RAM, like 1 GB for example?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: If so, I want to take that class.

Comment: I'm studying assembly language, just as a hobby, and I want to learn the basics, and how a PC works. I'm not a college student, just curious. Thanks for your time anyway =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The BIOS is a 16-bit program running in real mode, and in this mode it is possible to address only 1MB.

This is incorrect.

> 16-bit real mode does not limit the processor to 1MB of memory.
>
> While it's true that an x86 processor starts out in real mode, and
>   defaults to the 16-bit 8086 instruction set, there are extensions in
>   the 80286 instrution set. If you prefix an 8086 instruction with the
>   byte 0x67, this will allow that instruction access to a 32-bit
>   register, which has access to 2<sup>32</sup> bytes, or 4GiB of memory.
>
> If you are using a 64-bit processor, the processor can use PAE ([Physical Address Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)), which
>   gives the processor access to 2<sup>52</sup> bytes of memory, more than can be
>   physically installed on any modern motherboard.

Source [How BIOS can detect full extended memory size](https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-bios-can-detect-full-extended-memory-size/28927)

---

#### How does the BIOS determine the amount of available RAM, like 1 GB for example?

It uses methods that are documented in the datasheets for the memory controller ([northbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_%28computing%29)).

> Most BIOSes can't use any RAM until they detect the type of RAM installed, then detect the size of each memory module, then configure
>   the chipset to use the detected RAM.
>
> All of this depends on chipset specific methods, and is usually documented in the datasheets for the memory controller (northbridge).
>
> The RAM is unusable for running programs during this process. The BIOS initially is running from ROM, so it can play the necessary games
>   with the RAM chips. But it is completely impossible to do this from
>   inside any other program.

Source [Detecting Memory (x86)](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Thank you for providing your time to answer my question. Actually, I still have a lot to learn. PS: my question was answered very very fast LOL.

Comment: On detecting memory: the DIMMS have a small EPROM that says what they are and what timings should be used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect

Comment: The first quotation is neither correct, nor relevant to the question. First off, there is a typo that says "80286" when it should be "80386". Second, the ability to use 32-bit registers has nothing to do with the ability to address memory. When running in real mode, you're still limited to 20-bit address lines, regardless of the register size. Third, PAE is available on lots of processors that do not support 64-bit extensions. Fourth, the quotation's implication is also wrong. Real mode *is* limited to addressing only 1 MB; it just isn't necessary to *address* the memory to *count* it.